# Finding the equilibrium point of a system that rotates and oscillates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, centrifugal-force

I'm currently learning physics and I don't always know the right approach in order to solve a problem. I ran into a problem with some sort of oscillation combined with a circular motion.

Problem:
An object of mass  is placed in the configuration (on a tray) below between two identical springs.
The whole system rotates around an axis that passes through the middle of the tray with angular speed . Does this
system perform small oscillations? If it does, what are the oscillation frequency and its equilibrium position?

I proposed this in an older post, and kind of figured out the explanation. But something is still uncertain to me.

[image]

I started by choosing a system of coordinates with the origin placed in the center of the tray.

[image]

I moved the object a bit away from its initial position and tried to see what happens.

The equilibrium point can be explained through this equation: [image] (by using Newton's Laws)

What I need to prove first, is that the body will oscillate around a point. My intuition (because I cannot prove it) is that the oscillations will not take place around the center of the axis, but another point, once the system is in motion.

**How can I calculate the equilibrium point and demonstrate that I have harmonic oscillations around it?**

I used the following equation in order to find the period, but now I am not sure my judgment was right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I calculate the equilibrium point and demonstrate that I have
> harmonic oscillations around it?

The NEoM is:

$$m\ddot{x}=mx\omega^2-2kx$$

Or:

$$\ddot{x}+\frac{2k-m\omega^2}{m}x=0$$

Let:

$$\omega_{osc}^2=\frac{2k-m\omega^2}{m}$$

So that:

$$\ddot{x}+\omega_{osc}^2x=0$$

This is the classic ODE of a SHO, with general solution:

$$x(t)=c_1\sin(\omega_{osc} t)+c_2\cos(\omega_{osc} t)$$

The integration constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ are determined *from the initial conditions*, typically:
$$x(0)=x_0$$
$$v(0)=\dot{x}(0)=0$$

And you'll find the equilibrium point for $a(t)=\ddot{x}(t)=0$.